# C++ equivalent of Java >>>=? and problem with varint

Tags: java, c++

Here I have 2 functions one is in c++ and one is Java. Both have the same purpose:
C++:

```cpp
void VarIntToBufferArray(int* buffer, int in)
{
    std::vector<int> buffVect;
    int value = in;

    do {
        int temp = (int)(value & 0b01111111);
        value >> 7;
        if (value != 0) {
            temp |= 0b10000000;
        }
        buffVect.push_back(temp);
    } while (value != 0);


    buffer = &buffVect[0];
}
```

Java:

```
public static void writeVarInt(int value) {
    do {
        byte temp = (byte)(value & 0b01111111);
        // Note: >>> means that the sign bit is shifted with the rest of the number rather than being left alone
        value >>>= 7;
        if (value != 0) {
            temp |= 0b10000000;
        }
        writeByte(temp);
    } while (value != 0);
}
```

Something is wrong with C++ version of code because I get this output on C++:
`0 0 99 -35` and on Java version: `-35 -57 1` which should be. I think >> by itself can't replace >>>=. Any way of doing that?

Comment: `value >> 7;`  is a no-op. Did you mean `value >>= 7;`? But for the equivalent of `>>>`, you probably need `value = int(unsigned(value) >> 7);` In Java, a separate operator for "unsigned shift" is needed because Java lacks unsigned integral types.

Comment: In Java, do you mean the `>>=` operator?

Comment: With `value = int(unsigned(value) >> 7);`, I get output: -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460

Comment: What do you mean, you get output? The C++ code you've shown doesn't produce any output. In fact, the whole `VarIntToBufferArray` is an elaborate no-op, as it doesn't have any side effects.

Comment: `int buffer[sizeof(int)];
 VarIntToBufferArray(buffer, 25565);`

Comment: Again, `VarIntToBufferArray` call is a no-op. `buffer` starts with uninitialized contents before the call, and remains with uninitialized contents afterwards.

Comment: you are pointing buffer at an array that is deleted when the function ends, so buffer can (will) end up pointing at garbage.

Comment: @CraigR In fact, the OP ain't pointing no array anywhere. Assignment to `buffer` - a parameter passed by value - is not visible to the caller. Again, `VarIntToBufferArray` does absolutely nothing, doesn't change the state of the program in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: (Now getting same output as in Java)

```
template<typename T>
void convertUnderByteMax(T* temp) {
    if (*temp > 127) {
        *temp -= 256;
    }
}

void VarIntToBufferArray(std::vector<int>& buffer, int in)
{
    int value = in;

    do {
        int temp = (int)(value & 0b01111111);
        value = ((unsigned int) value) >> 7;

        if (value != 0) {
            temp |= 0b10000000;
        }

        convertUnderByteMax(&temp);
        buffer.push_back(temp);
    } while (value != 0);


}
```